# TableView did not show data from CoreData

Tags: core-data, uitableview, segue

i work on project where is TableViewController as initial controller. Then i have CoreData where i store my data. From my first TableViewController i get to ViewController via push segue in storyboard. In that ViewController i add data to my Core data, but when ViewController dismiss and TableViewController is back my table is still empty.

here is my code for table:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
_managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest*request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription*name = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"nameEntity" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:name];

NSError*error = nil;
NSMutableArray*mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {

}
 [self setMutableArray:mutableFetchResults];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

than my code for table row:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
} 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return mutableArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Name";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
Name*name = (Name*) [mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];

cell.textLabel.text = name.shop;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = name.date;
return cell;
}
```

and here code where i store that data in my ViewController:

```
- (IBAction)addData:(id)sender;{
Name *name = [NSEntityDescription     insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"nameEntity"   inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[name setShop:textField.text];
NSDate*date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:date];
[zoznam setDate:dateString];
```

Comment: Just a small tip, your "name" class should have a capital N. It's standard for classes to have uppercase letters first. Helps readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

in your viewDidLoad which is not going to be invoked when you dismiss your viewController. If you would like to reload your dataSource, try this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
      _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

      NSFetchRequest*request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
      NSEntityDescription*name = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"nameEntity"  inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
      [request setEntity:name];

      NSError*error = nil;
      NSMutableArray*mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]mutableCopy];
      [self setMutableArray:mutableFetchResults];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: post the rest of your dataSource methods. numberOfSectionsInTableView:
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: now its work, but that data are not stored to coreData correctly, because when i start my app one more time, table is clean again

Comment: That is out of scope of this question. I would ask another question relating to Core Data